# checking if a current time falls in a particular interval in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

**EDIT**: Please take care to introduce UTC timing in your answer. Since doing things on client side will lead to different time zones.

In javascript, i can get the current time, hour and minute as follows:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentHour = currentTime.getHours();
var currentMinute = currentTime.getMinutes();
```

Now i have to perform a task only if the current time false in an interval with a fixed time. 
Say there is a `fixed time 10:30 AM`. Users can perform a certain task iff the `current time`, is `4 hours behind` the `current time` or `1 hour ahead` of the `fixed time`.

**meaning users can perform the task from 6:30 AM to 11:30 AM.**

I tried getting the current hours and doing

```
start = fixed_time - 4;
end = fixed_time + 1;
if currentHour< end or currentHour > start{
do some stuff; 
}
```

But this ignores the minutes, how to take care of that?
**Otherwise, how could i figure if the current time lies between 6:30 AM and 11:30 AM?**

Answer (score 2):

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var startTime = new Date(2012, 3, 8, 6, 30, 0, 0); //6:30am today
var endTime = new Date(2012, 3, 8, 11, 30, 0, 0); //11:30am today

if ((currentTime.getTime() > startTime.getTime()) && (currentTime.getTime() < endTime.getTime())
{
   //current time is between start and end so do what you need to do
}
```

If you need it to be more dynamic you can

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var startTime = new Date();
startTime.setHours(6);
startTime.setMinutes(30);
var endTime = new Date();
endTime.setHours(11);
endTime.setMinutes(30);

if ((currentTime.getTime() > startTime.getTime()) && (currentTime.getTime() < endTime.getTime())
{
   //current time is between start and end so do what you need to do
}
```

Comment: but i am hardcoding the date as well, i want only the hour and minutes to be hardcoded.

Comment: Or you could use the number of hours behind and ahead instead.

Comment: How could i get the UTC timings? Because client side timings will change stuff for me.

Comment: Can we convert that into a function so If i have to make multiple calls I can use the function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use getTime() method which returns the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970:

```
currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
```

Then all you need is to calculate the difference between your fixed time and current time in milliseconds. 4 hours equals to 14,400,000 (4*60*60*1000) milliseconds.

Comment: There is a list of date object methods at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp. There you'll see that parse() method parses a datetime string and converts it to milliseconds, which may help you.

Comment: Http://w3fools.com - use mdn instead

Answer (score 1):

You can compare dates to one another. So, using the current date and time you can compare that to dates with a fixed time set. Something like:

```
var now    = new Date
   ,lower  = new Date
   ,upper  = new Date;
//determine limits
lower.setHours(6);
lower.setMinutes(30);
upper.setMinutes(30);
upper.setHours(11);
//tests
now = new Date('2012/04/08 22:00');
console.log(now >= lower && now <= upper); //=> false
now = new Date('2012/04/08 07:00');
console.log(now >= lower && now <= upper); //=> true
```

Comment: i want only the UTC time zone timings, because running the above code at different places would ruin things for me.

Comment: Not sure how to solve that. There are several UTC methods available like `setUTCHours/setUTCMinutes` or `getTimezoneOffset`. Maybe I don't understand: you want to restrict the user to a start-/end time in your timezone only?

Comment: Yes i want that to restrict them. But keeping UTC as standard. so for the variable now i wanted the current utc time, because lower and upper are already in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

```
var startTime = '01 AM'; // or var startTime = '01:00 AM';
var endTime   = '09 AM'; // or var startTime = '09:00 AM';

var now       = new Date();

if(now < convert_time(endTime) && now > convert_time(startTime)){
  alert("With in a range");
}else{
 alert("Out of range");
}    


function convert_actual_time(time) {
 if(time.indexOf(" ") != -1){
  split1 = time.split(" ");
  splitTime = split1[0];
  splitZone = split1[1];
 }
 if(splitTime.indexOf(":") != -1){
  split2 = splitTime.split(":");
  setHours  = split2[0];
  setMins   = split2[1];        
 }else{
  setHours  = splitTime;
  setMins   = "00";
}   
 if(splitZone.toLowerCase() == "pm"){   
  setHours = parseInt(setHours)+12; 
 }  
 date = new Date();
 date.setHours(setHours);
 date.setMinutes(setMins);

 return date;
}
```

Try with this code