# Javascript - How to check if local current time falls within a specific est time range [all timezone]

Tags: javascript, time, intervals

How to check if local current time falls within a specific est time range [all timezone].

I have to set the value as true in particular variable, if local current time(HH:mm) falls within a specific est time(HH:mm) range.

If you compare with EST to IST that difference will be below i mentioned

Indian TimeZone - 2 hoours 30 minutes front next day

If EST to Huwaii

Huwai TimeZone - 6 hours back - previous day

I have input parameters

```
EventStartDate
EventEndDate
EventStartTime
EventEndTime
```

For Example

EST time was

```
   Current Date - 23-03-2017

   Event StartTime 2:00 AM

   Event EndTime   6:00 AM
```

same as in Huwaii

```
  Current Date - 22-03-2017

  Event has to start : 8:00 PM

  Event has to end   : 12:00 AM
```

In this case variable has to be true otherwise it would be an false.
Because server will be in EST imagine is in US but loacl time is Huwaii

The code shoul work for 
local  current time falls within a specific est time range for all timezone

Can  any one help me!!
I need code in Javascript

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't understand your requirement at all. Can you provide your real use case?

Comment: Hi Lcycool,I updated my question can you please help on this?

Comment: You can have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061021/checking-if-a-current-time-falls-in-a-particular-interval-in-javascript)! might help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [checking if a current time falls in a particular interval in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061021/checking-if-a-current-time-falls-in-a-particular-interval-in-javascript)